# DateTime.Now Returned Weird Date

Tags: c#, .net

I have a WinForms application that was written in C# .NET 3.5.  This application interacts with a SQL Server 2008. Whenever I add a record into the database, I have a `DateAdd` column that I insert `DateTime.Now` into.  For whatever reason, I have 4 records with odd dates:

```
'1980-01-03 23:08:43.970'    
'1980-01-03 23:08:44.157'    
'1980-01-03 23:08:44.530'    
'1980-01-03 23:08:45.547'
```

The records before and after these all have proper dates of `'2011-05-29 XX:XX:XX.XXX'`.  Users have no access to modify the date fields in any application.

Is there any reason that the dates would change like this?  Users have no access to modify their system time, which I'm assuming is where DateTime.Now gathers the date from.

Basically, I've come to the conclusion that there is either a bug, or a user has a Delorean fully equipped with a flux capacitor...

Comment: Perhaps one user has set his system time to be back in 1980 ? Other than that, I agreee with Jason.

Comment: Users have no access to the system time.  Also, what other information do you need?

Comment: Is the column actually of a date-like type? Is DateTime.Now executed on the client or the server? Do dates before and after 2000-01-01 look different on your SQL server?

Comment: @aaron: a PC with a faulty BIOS clock can produce wrong times without user involvement.

Comment: I agree with the BIOS being the potential cause here, I had a computer where the battery on the motherboard died and the date would reset to 1-1-1980 every time the computer was restarted.

Comment: @David: the column is a datetime column.  DateTime.Now is executed client-side.  Dates look the same as they always have with the exception of these 4.

Comment: @Joel&David:  I'll get some of the networking guys here to check the client PC for faulty hardware.  Thanks for that suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is a client windows app, check the system time on the machines that the users in question are using. Also, I don't know if this is best practice or not, but I find it easier to maintain if I use GetDate() in SQLSERVER rather than passing the date from the C#.NET application in cases were I need to record the current time.

Comment: @David @Joel I think you guys are right. I am always finding this when batteries go out. That is why I think it is a best practice to never trust a client application to grab the current date and time. Always do this on the server where you have control.

Comment: Can anyone answer if that is the standard?  I've done it before in other applications, but I was told to not use it because it puts more stress on the SQL box (which I can see as being true, but I find it hard to believe that getting the current date can put THAT much stress...unless I have thousands of entries all trying to get the date at the same time).

Comment: @Aaron That sounds like BS. I would consider it a best practice to set the date server side, and the only way to control the date reliably. If that's really going to stress your SQL server, you need a new server ASAP!

Comment: Cerainly never put GetDate() inside a filter or join statement, but if you are not calling for each row, then I wouldn't worry about it. I used to be incredibly concerned with standards, but I got tired of having bugs in my app. If either me or the dba is going to look bad, it isn't going to be me :) Seriously though, standards are good starting places, but it seems to me to be a bad idea to trust a client machine for something like a date or time. You always need a centralized standard. A web app would be an exception since all of its code is run on a central server.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you.  I'll change this, and then get someone to check out those client PCs for bad hardware.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan even then, though, you never know at what point your web app may get scaled across a web farm. It's always best to plan ahead for that kind of thing; who wants to have to go back through and find everywhere a date could possibly get set? It would still be better to set the dates in the database.

Comment: @Joel agreed. That certainly makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

The motherboard battery on one of your users computers is dead - look for the "Windows 98 Compatible" sticker on the front of a (now) yellow Compaq desktop under someones desk. That computer was powered on 2 days before writing a record to your database. The next time it is completely shutdown or power cycled it will go back to Jan 1, 1980.

Best practice would be to have the database assign the date (set the column default as GETDATE()). This way a single date scheme is used and you don't have to worry about users changing dates, events from different users appearing in the wrong order because their computers where a few minutes off one another, or the times being several hours off because of incorrect timezone settings.